# Outrageous miners fees

Tags: transaction-fees

My BRD wallet just charged a 27 dollar miners fee TO SEND 50 dollars worth of bitcoin!! 1/3 of 75 bucks went to a miners fee? 55e7f51a96ecd8d25a1566346bff76e2985a5aed4fe279e44d75f991cf0a993a

Comment: Can someone cancel this before it gets confirmed?

Answer (score 1):

Your wallet seems to have wildly inaccurate fee estimation.

Currently, for next block mining, you should be paying around 1/8th of that fee - 1/10th or less for next 2-4 blocks.

Unfortunately, that transaction cannot really be cancelled - you could attempt to double spend it, but the fee is so high that you'd end up spending even more to potentially get a double spend mined, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: That's pretty much what thought. Why would myBRD wallet suddenly change miners fees like that?

Comment: Whatever system they use to estimate a good fee rate is probably broken in some way, or not accurate when there are sudden changes in the mempool. Your best bet would be to reach out and ask them directly

Comment: I recommend you using https://mempool.observer/ to see the mining fees on the next blocks. It gives you an idea about how much does it cost to mine a tx. But be aware that the current cost is something dynamic, and a lot of txs can arrive suddenly paying more fees than the one you have sent, sending you back in the queue.